# Interrupt on one core and tasklet schedule on different core

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am not able to address the below issue:

Suppose, i am getting interrupt on core-1 and i want tasklet to be run on core-2 so to perform fast data processing.

I want to know :

a) Is it achievable ? If yes then is there any kernel API which helps into it ?

b) If (a) is achievable then what are the implication on the caching front ?

c) What are the challenges in the coding & design perspective ?

Regards,

Manish

Comment: 1. Is it a hard requirement to use a tasklet or a workqueue item would be fine as well? 2. Do you need any synchronization between the interrupt handler and the tasklet?

Comment: If you provide more info about what you are trying to accomplish (what kind of problem your code is ultimately trying to solve), the experts out there could give you more useful suggestions. It might be an easier way to solve the problem.

Comment: There is no sync between tasklet and isr. I would like to know more workqueue solution if i can tied it on other core.